# How to identify methods and properties of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

How to identify the methods and properties of an object in javascript?And how many numbner of method & events are their for each object?

Comment: All user-defined properties are enumerable by default. You can simply loop through them to check whatever you need. It's not clear what you mean by `And how many numbner of method & events are their for each object?`

Comment: total number of properties and methods for inbuilt and user defined objects ?

Comment: Can you show your code snippet, because I tend to think you want to examine not only the object but it's prototype also?

Answer (score 0):

If you using Google browser make use of the console window. Enter the valid object and you may find a drop-down button which enlists all the methods and its respective properties registered to it.

Comment: What is a “Goggle browser”? Any modern browser has a console.

Comment: Yeah!! i mean the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily know what are Object keys and then you can also get their perticular value

Object.keys(yourObj)

if you know the property and want to check whether it exists in your object or not then

youObj.hasOwnProperty("propName")